# What is wrong with my constructor class for jpa query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, constructor

**This is my query**:

```
  @Query("SELECT new Users(user.id, user.createdBy, user.createdOne, user.email, user.firstname, user.isActive, user.lastModifiedBy, user.lastModifiedOn, user.lastname, user.password, " +
          "user.username, user.rolesToUsers, user.clientName, user.groupsToUsers, user.mobileNumber, user.userAddress, user.logiUserId, " +
          "modifiedByUser.username, createdByUser.username) " +
          "FROM  Users user inner join ClientName client  on client.cid = user.clientName " +
          "left join Users modifiedByUser on modifiedByUser.id = user.modifiedBy " +
          "left join Users createdByUser on createdByUser.id = user.createdBy WHERE client.cid =?1")
  public Optional<List<Users>> findAllByClientIdModifiedUser(Long cid);
```

**My constructor is**:

```
  public Users(Long id, Long createdBy, Date createdOne, String email, String firstname, String isActive, Long lastModifiedBy, Date lastModifiedOn, String lastname,
               String password, String username, List<RolesToUser> rolesToUsers, ClientName clientName, List<GroupsToUser> groupsToUsers, Long mobileNumber,
               UserAddress userAddress, String logiUserId, String modifiedByUser, String createdByUser) {

    this.id = id;
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    this.createdOne = createdOne;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.isActive = isActive;
    this.lastModifiedBy = lastModifiedBy;
    this.lastModifiedOn = lastModifiedOn;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.password = password;
    this.username = username;
    this.rolesToUsers = rolesToUsers;
    this.clientName = clientName;
    this.groupsToUsers = groupsToUsers;
    this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    this.userAddress = userAddress;
    this.logiUserId = logiUserId;
    this.modifiedByUser = modifiedByUser;
    this.createdByUser = createdByUser;
  }
```

**Error I am getting is**:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.Users]. Expected arguments are: long, long, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.util.Collection, com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.ClientName, java.util.Collection, long, com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.UserAddress, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String [SELECT new Users(user.id, user.createdBy, user.createdOne, user.email, user.firstname, user.isActive, user.lastModifiedBy, user.lastModifiedOn, user.lastname, user.password, user.username, user.rolesToUsers, user.clientName, user.groupsToUsers, user.mobileNumber, user.userAddress, user.logiUserId, modifiedByUser.username, createdByUser.username) FROM  com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.Users user inner join com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.ClientName client  on client.cid = user.clientName left join com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.Users modifiedByUser on modifiedByUser.id = user.lastModifiedBy left join com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.Users createdByUser on createdByUser.id = user.createdBy WHERE client.cid =?1]

Comment: Note that JPA entities need to have a no-args constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message:

> Expected arguments are: long, long, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, java.util.Date, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, **java.util.Collection**, com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.ClientName, **java.util.Collection**, long, com.rightdata.dextrus.db.model.UserAddress, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String

And your constructor's arguments are:

> Long id, Long createdBy, Date createdOne, String email, String firstname, String isActive, Long lastModifiedBy, Date lastModifiedOn, String lastname,
> String password, String username, **List<RolesToUser>** rolesToUsers, ClientName clientName, **List<GroupsToUser>** groupsToUsers, Long mobileNumber,
> UserAddress userAddress, String logiUserId, String modifiedByUser, String createdByUser

A List is a Collection, but a Collection is not (always) a list.

Change your constructor to:

```
public Users(
    Long id,
    Long createdBy,
    Date createdOne,
    String email,
    String firstname,
    String isActive,
    Long lastModifiedBy,
    Date lastModifiedOn,
    String lastname,
    String password,
    String username,
    Collection<RolesToUser> rolesToUsers, // list=>collection
    ClientName clientName,
    Collection<GroupsToUser> groupsToUsers, // list=>collection
    Long mobileNumber,
    UserAddress userAddress,
    String logiUserId,
    String modifiedByUser,
    String createdByUser) {
```

If that still doesn't work, check if boxed `Long` vs primitive `long` causes problems.

Whenever you encounter a problem such as this, it's good to divide it into smaller problems. Change the constructor to a single parameter and see if it works. If it does: add the next parameter. If it does not: congratulations, you have found your problematic param. Rinse and repeat until you have added all params again or found the culprit.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is working for me and able to run the code. But when I hit the method I am getting this new error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '. as col_11_0_, users0_.client_id as col_12_0_, . as col_13_0_, users0_.mobile_n' at line 1.

Comment: @praneethpuppali `client_id` is not part of the query that you have shown. If you have a new question, please post a new question; this question was about incompatible types in the constructor. Check your query and apply the same troubleshooting technique: reduce to the smallest possible query, then start adding back parts until it breaks.